# BulletPhysics Linker Error for VS2010 , for sample project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker, bulletphysics

Like any other BulletPhysics app, my VS2010 project refers to three other projects : BulletDynamics , Bullet3Collision and LinearMath.

It is a simple BulletPhysics test project, I tried multiple options but none of them seem to work :

1. Individual projects (BulletDynamics , Bullet3Collision and LinearMath) -> properties -> Librarian -> Link Library dependencies.
2. BulletTestProject -> Properties -> Common Properties -> Framework and References -> Added above three projects with Link Library dependencies true.
3. BulletTestProject -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Add additional Libraries & -> Input -> Add aditional dependencies.

Tried above three but none seem to work.
Any help is appreciated to fix the linker error.

Edit :

Follwing

```
4>BulletHelloWorld.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall btCollisionDispatcher::btCollisionDispatcher(class btCollisionConfiguration *)" (??0btCollisionDispatcher@@QAE@PAVbtCollisionConfiguration@@@Z) referenced in function _main
4>BulletHelloWorld.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall btDefaultCollisionConfiguration::btDefaultCollisionConfiguration(struct btDefaultCollisionConstructionInfo const &)" (??0btDefaultCollisionConfiguration@@QAE@ABUbtDefaultCollisionConstructionInfo@@@Z) referenced in function _main
4>BulletHelloWorld.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall btDbvtBroadphase::btDbvtBroadphase(class btOverlappingPairCache *)" (??0btDbvtBroadphase@@QAE@PAVbtOverlappingPairCache@@@Z) referenced in function _main
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall btCollisionWorld::btCollisionWorld(class btDispatcher *,class btBroadphaseInterface *,class btCollisionConfiguration *)" (??0btCollisionWorld@@QAE@PAVbtDispatcher@@PAVbtBroadphaseInterface@@PAVbtCollisionConfiguration@@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall btDynamicsWorld::btDynamicsWorld(class btDispatcher *,class btBroadphaseInterface *,class btCollisionConfiguration *)" (??0btDynamicsWorld@@QAE@PAVbtDispatcher@@PAVbtBroadphaseInterface@@PAVbtCollisionConfiguration@@@Z)
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall btCollisionWorld::updateAabbs(void)" (?updateAabbs@btCollisionWorld@@UAEXXZ)
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall btCollisionWorld::computeOverlappingPairs(void)" (?computeOverlappingPairs@btCollisionWorld@@UAEXXZ)
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall btCollisionWorld::debugDrawObject(class btTransform const &,class btCollisionShape const *,class btVector3 const &)" (?debugDrawObject@btCollisionWorld@@UAEXABVbtTransform@@PBVbtCollisionShape@@ABVbtVector3@@@Z)
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall btCollisionWorld::rayTest(class btVector3 const &,class btVector3 const &,struct btCollisionWorld::RayResultCallback &)const " (?rayTest@btCollisionWorld@@UBEXABVbtVector3@@0AAURayResultCallback@1@@Z)
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall btCollisionWorld::addCollisionObject(class btCollisionObject *,short,short)" (?addCollisionObject@btCollisionWorld@@UAEXPAVbtCollisionObject@@FF@Z)
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall btCollisionWorld::removeCollisionObject(class btCollisionObject *)" (?removeCollisionObject@btCollisionWorld@@UAEXPAVbtCollisionObject@@@Z)
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall btCollisionWorld::performDiscreteCollisionDetection(void)" (?performDiscreteCollisionDetection@btCollisionWorld@@UAEXXZ)
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall btCollisionWorld::serialize(class btSerializer *)" (?serialize@btCollisionWorld@@UAEXPAVbtSerializer@@@Z)
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall btCollisionWorld::~btCollisionWorld(void)" (??1btCollisionWorld@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall btDynamicsWorld::~btDynamicsWorld(void)" (??1btDynamicsWorld@@UAE@XZ)
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall btCollisionObject::setActivationState(int)const " (?setActivationState@btCollisionObject@@QBEXH@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall btRigidBody::updateDeactivation(float)" (?updateDeactivation@btRigidBody@@QAEXM@Z)
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall btConvexShape::~btConvexShape(void)" (??1btConvexShape@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall btConvexInternalShape::~btConvexInternalShape(void)" (??1btConvexInternalShape@@UAE@XZ)
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall btCollisionShape::getBoundingSphere(class btVector3 &,float &)const " (?getBoundingSphere@btCollisionShape@@UBEXAAVbtVector3@@AAM@Z)
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual float __thiscall btCollisionShape::getAngularMotionDisc(void)const " (?getAngularMotionDisc@btCollisionShape@@UBEMXZ)
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual float __thiscall btCollisionShape::getContactBreakingThreshold(float)const " (?getContactBreakingThreshold@btCollisionShape@@UBEMM@Z)
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall btConvexInternalShape::setLocalScaling(class btVector3 const &)" (?setLocalScaling@btConvexInternalShape@@UAEXABVbtVector3@@@Z)
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall btCollisionShape::serializeSingleShape(class btSerializer *)const " (?serializeSingleShape@btCollisionShape@@UBEXPAVbtSerializer@@@Z)
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class btVector3 __thiscall btConvexInternalShape::localGetSupportingVertex(class btVector3 const &)const " (?localGetSupportingVertex@btConvexInternalShape@@UBE?AVbtVector3@@ABV2@@Z)
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall btConvexShape::project(class btTransform const &,class btVector3 const &,float &,float &)const " (?project@btConvexShape@@UBEXABVbtTransform@@ABVbtVector3@@AAM2@Z)
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall btConvexInternalShape::getAabbSlow(class btTransform const &,class btVector3 &,class btVector3 &)const " (?getAabbSlow@btConvexInternalShape@@UBEXABVbtTransform@@AAVbtVector3@@1@Z)
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual char const * __thiscall btCollisionShape::serialize(void *,class btSerializer *)const " (?serialize@btCollisionShape@@UBEPBDPAXPAVbtSerializer@@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual char const * __thiscall btConvexInternalShape::serialize(void *,class btSerializer *)const " (?serialize@btConvexInternalShape@@UBEPBDPAXPAVbtSerializer@@@Z)
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: __thiscall btConvexInternalShape::btConvexInternalShape(void)" (??0btConvexInternalShape@@IAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall btSphereShape::btSphereShape(float)" (??0btSphereShape@@QAE@M@Z)
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall btSphereShape::getAabb(class btTransform const &,class btVector3 &,class btVector3 &)const " (?getAabb@btSphereShape@@UBEXABVbtTransform@@AAVbtVector3@@1@Z)
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall btSphereShape::calculateLocalInertia(float,class btVector3 &)const " (?calculateLocalInertia@btSphereShape@@UBEXMAAVbtVector3@@@Z)
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class btVector3 __thiscall btSphereShape::localGetSupportingVertex(class btVector3 const &)const " (?localGetSupportingVertex@btSphereShape@@UBE?AVbtVector3@@ABV2@@Z)
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class btVector3 __thiscall btSphereShape::localGetSupportingVertexWithoutMargin(class btVector3 const &)const " (?localGetSupportingVertexWithoutMargin@btSphereShape@@UBE?AVbtVector3@@ABV2@@Z)
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall btSphereShape::batchedUnitVectorGetSupportingVertexWithoutMargin(class btVector3 const *,class btVector3 *,int)const " (?batchedUnitVectorGetSupportingVertexWithoutMargin@btSphereShape@@UBEXPBVbtVector3@@PAV2@H@Z)
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static float __cdecl btManifoldResult::calculateCombinedRestitution(class btCollisionObject const *,class btCollisionObject const *)" (?calculateCombinedRestitution@btManifoldResult@@SAMPBVbtCollisionObject@@0@Z) referenced in function "protected: virtual void __thiscall btDiscreteDynamicsWorld::integrateTransforms(float)" (?integrateTransforms@btDiscreteDynamicsWorld@@MAEXM@Z)
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall btCollisionWorld::convexSweepTest(class btConvexShape const *,class btTransform const &,class btTransform const &,struct btCollisionWorld::ConvexResultCallback &,float)const " (?convexSweepTest@btCollisionWorld@@QBEXPBVbtConvexShape@@ABVbtTransform@@1AAUConvexResultCallback@1@M@Z) referenced in function "protected: virtual void __thiscall btDiscreteDynamicsWorld::integrateTransforms(float)" (?integrateTransforms@btDiscreteDynamicsWorld@@MAEXM@Z)
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: void __thiscall btCollisionWorld::serializeCollisionObjects(class btSerializer *)" (?serializeCollisionObjects@btCollisionWorld@@IAEXPAVbtSerializer@@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall btDiscreteDynamicsWorld::serialize(class btSerializer *)" (?serialize@btDiscreteDynamicsWorld@@UAEXPAVbtSerializer@@@Z)
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall btCollisionWorld::debugDrawWorld(void)" (?debugDrawWorld@btCollisionWorld@@UAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall btDiscreteDynamicsWorld::debugDrawWorld(void)" (?debugDrawWorld@btDiscreteDynamicsWorld@@UAEXXZ)
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall btSimulationIslandManager::btSimulationIslandManager(void)" (??0btSimulationIslandManager@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall btDiscreteDynamicsWorld::btDiscreteDynamicsWorld(class btDispatcher *,class btBroadphaseInterface *,class btConstraintSolver *,class btCollisionConfiguration *)" (??0btDiscreteDynamicsWorld@@QAE@PAVbtDispatcher@@PAVbtBroadphaseInterface@@PAVbtConstraintSolver@@PAVbtCollisionConfiguration@@@Z)
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall btSimulationIslandManager::buildAndProcessIslands(class btDispatcher *,class btCollisionWorld *,struct btSimulationIslandManager::IslandCallback *)" (?buildAndProcessIslands@btSimulationIslandManager@@QAEXPAVbtDispatcher@@PAVbtCollisionWorld@@PAUIslandCallback@1@@Z) referenced in function "protected: virtual void __thiscall btDiscreteDynamicsWorld::solveConstraints(struct btContactSolverInfo &)" (?solveConstraints@btDiscreteDynamicsWorld@@MAEXAAUbtContactSolverInfo@@@Z)
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static float __cdecl btManifoldResult::calculateCombinedFriction(class btCollisionObject const *,class btCollisionObject const *)" (?calculateCombinedFriction@btManifoldResult@@SAMPBVbtCollisionObject@@0@Z) referenced in function "protected: void __thiscall btDiscreteDynamicsWorld::createPredictiveContacts(float)" (?createPredictiveContacts@btDiscreteDynamicsWorld@@IAEXM@Z)
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall btPersistentManifold::addManifoldPoint(class btManifoldPoint const &,bool)" (?addManifoldPoint@btPersistentManifold@@QAEHABVbtManifoldPoint@@_N@Z) referenced in function "protected: void __thiscall btDiscreteDynamicsWorld::createPredictiveContacts(float)" (?createPredictiveContacts@btDiscreteDynamicsWorld@@IAEXM@Z)
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btRigidBody.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual char const * __thiscall btCollisionObject::serialize(void *,class btSerializer *)const " (?serialize@btCollisionObject@@UBEPBDPAXPAVbtSerializer@@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual char const * __thiscall btRigidBody::serialize(void *,class btSerializer *)const " (?serialize@btRigidBody@@UBEPBDPAXPAVbtSerializer@@@Z)
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btRigidBody.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall btCollisionObject::~btCollisionObject(void)" (??1btCollisionObject@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function __unwindfunclet$??0btRigidBody@@QAE@ABUbtRigidBodyConstructionInfo@0@@Z$0
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btTypedConstraint.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall btCollisionObject::~btCollisionObject(void)" (??1btCollisionObject@@UAE@XZ)
4>BulletDynamics_RelWithDebugInfo.lib(btRigidBody.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall btCollisionObject::btCollisionObject(void)" (??0btCollisionObject@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall btRigidBody::btRigidBody(struct btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo const &)" (??0btRigidBody@@QAE@ABUbtRigidBodyConstructionInfo@0@@Z)
4>C:\Users\jay\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\BulletTest\Debug\BulletTest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 41 unresolved externals
```

========== Rebuild All: 3 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: can you provide the exact (full) linker error?

Comment: Set the "show progress" linker option to see what libraries are actually used by the linker.

Comment: already set to Display all progress messages (/VERBOSE)

Comment: added full log at http://pastebin.com/74vQ6Rsa